# 3/12 memory slots don't work - Dead processor or motherboard

Tags: memory, hardware, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell PowerEdge M630 blade with 2x Xeon E5-2630 v4 processors which support quad-channel memory. The blade supports 24 sticks of RAM, 12 for each processor, 4 channels of three slots.

I added RAM to fill it up (24x 16GB sticks), but the system says there is only 336 GB, not 384GB, and the iDRAC inventory shows slots B3, B7, and B11 are not populated. There are no BIOS warnings or iDRAC warnings.

I switched the sticks around to make sure that the issue wasn't with specific dead sticks. My next thought was to try switching the processors to see if it is an issue with the processor or the socket/motherboard, but before I go through the trouble, is there anything else I should check?

,[image: RAM layout]

Comment: With certain (power hungry) CPU's you can't populate all memory slots. https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-ca/poweredge-m630/m630ownersmanual/general-memory-module-installation-guidelines?guid=guid-24600dd1-427d-4c18-9bdd-5749c5082356&lang=en-us

Comment: @HBruijn This processor has an 85w TDP, plus I have 21 DIMMs showing, not 20, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: open up a support case on the vendor if this is a business environment or relationship with business

Comment: @djdomi I am sorry to say that this is the least helpful comment I have ever seen in the 13 years I have been on this site.

Comment: I did more research on the memory limits - having a more powerful processor only limits the ram installed because the heatsink overhangs the slots.

Comment: what is the business usage in here, yakatz - if i had a problem with my dell server i gonna screw dell with my 24/7 nbd support, thats how i as a business administrator do it and dont break my head about it , but oyu may have used a non standard configuration or similar, which may need to be enabled in the bios to use unrecommended settings from the vendor.

Comment: If I had support from Dell, I would have already asked them. I am trying to extend the life of old hardware so it doesn't end up in the shredder. The M630 is 7 years old and you can't even buy support from Dell for it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was likely an issue with uneven pressure of the heatsink on the processor. I went to swap the two processors to see whether that would move the issue and I found a piece of some kind of tape caught under the heatsink. When I put the processors back, all the RAM showed up.

[image: Tape under heatsink]